# System.Drawing.Image FromStream inconsistently returning out of memory exception

Tags: c#, image, arrays

I am trying to improve our web applications image upload feature which stores images in to a database as a byte array and then reads them out later and puts them in to an HTML image tag to be displayed.

In order to display all the images uploaded we have a separate set of methods to retrieve a thumbnail image which involves reading out of the database, converting to a memory stream and then using that to create a C# Image followed by the .GetThumbnail method before converting it back to a byte array via another memory stream object.

A grid loads up all the data (image name, description, category, etc...) then calls a separate URL with the image id to retrieve a thumbnail image. This URL returns an C# MVC ImageResult. When I call this URL by itself it loads up the correct thumbnail with no problem. However, when I call the grid it loads up other images fine and then falls over with a Out Of Memory Exception. If I skip over this it will continue to load up the other images ok too.

At first I thought it might be due to leaving one of the streams open but everything is enclosed in a using with Dispose() and Close() called on both memory streams (the first to convert it to an image, the second to convert it back to a byte array) in finally blocks.

I am completely out of ideas as it looks like the byte array is the same, the method being called is the same but in one instance it works and the other it doesn't.

I have copied offending code which is the method that converts the image to a thumbnail via our Image object (passed in as the 4th parameters) consistently falls over on the line System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms) line.

```
  private static void ConvertToImage(int size, bool fixWidth, bool fixHeight, Image img)
    {
        byte[] picbyte = img.Img;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(picbyte))
        { 
            try
            {

                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                int width = image.Width;
                int height = image.Height;

                if (fixWidth && !fixHeight)
                {
                    height = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)height / width) * size);
                    width = size;
                }

                if (fixHeight && !fixWidth)
                {
                    width = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)width / height) * size);
                    height = size;
                }

                if ((fixWidth && fixHeight) || (!fixWidth && !fixHeight))
                {
                    width = size;
                    height = size;
                }

                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));

                int ptrInt = 0;
                Marshal.WriteInt32(ptr, ptrInt);

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
                using (image = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, delegate () { return false; }, ptr))
                { 
                    try
                    {
                        image.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        img.Img = ms2.ToArray();
                        img.MIMEType = "image/png";
                        image.Dispose();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        ms2.Close();
                        ms2.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally //Ensure we close the stream if anything happens.
            {
                ms.Close();
                ms.Dispose();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: It is a plain bug in your code, you never disposed the original `image` object.  You reassign it with the thumbnail, losing the opportunity to dispose it.  That typically won't last long, OOM gets to be likely when you forget to dispose images.  You probably would not have created this bug if you just had used a different variable to store the thumbnail reference.  Never micro-optimize local variables.

Comment: Disagree with the close reason.  This isn't a typo, this is a bug that even with a decade of .NET experience, I personally didn't notice it right away either until reading the explanation below.

Comment: Just trying my luck here, are you by any chance has solved this issue? because i getting the same problem here. For some images, i can be successfully created, and some others is failed due to OutOfMemory exception

Answer (score 5):

GDI (the thing classes like `Image` and `Bitmap` are wrappers for) is bad about throwing a `OutOfMemoryExecption` when a better exception would have been the better named, non exsitant, `OutOfHandlesException`.

When working with images in .NET you ***MUST*** always dispose of your resources, the objects you are working with are often classes that do not take a lot of managed memory but hold on to limited unmanaged resources. Because they do not put much memory pressure on the Garbage Collector if you create a lot of them you can easily run out of [GDI handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx) before the GC runs and collects them.

At the top of your function you do

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

then later on you do

```
 using (image = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, delegate () { return false; }, ptr))
```

This is causing you to lose the reference to the first `Image` object without disposing it. Use a different variable name for your thumbnail and put that first image in a `using` block.

---

P.S. Your `.Close();` and `.Dispose()` calls are unnessesary. Putting the disposeable objects inside a `using` block does both those operations, you can get rid of all of your try-finally blocks and get rid of the extra `image.Dispose()` call. Also your `ptr` is not correct, [the MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage(v=vs.110).aspx) you should be passing in [`IntPtr.Zero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero(v=vs.110).aspx) not the value 0 written to a pointer.

Here is a quickly updated version that has all the fixes.

```
private static void ConvertToImage(int size, bool fixWidth, bool fixHeight, Image img)
{
    byte[] picbyte = img.Img;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(picbyte))
    using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))
    { 
        int width = image.Width;
        int height = image.Height;

        if (fixWidth && !fixHeight)
        {
            height = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)height / width) * size);
            width = size;
        }

        if (fixHeight && !fixWidth)
        {
            width = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)width / height) * size);
            height = size;
        }

        if ((fixWidth && fixHeight) || (!fixWidth && !fixHeight))
        {
            width = size;
            height = size;
        }

        using(MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream())
        using (var thumnailImage = image.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, delegate () { return false; }, IntPtr.Zero))
        { 
            thumnailImage.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            img.Img = ms2.ToArray();
            img.MIMEType = "image/png";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input so far but this also seems to be falling over at the same point. I even tried putting a using around the first Image variable too which still didn't help. Any other ideas? Its certainly appreciated.